# how to get value of more than one text box in a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some text boxes in my page. I want to get all text box values in an array and insert in to table of database.

Is there any option to work by loop

Comment: Please provide example markup code so that people can help you

Answer (score 11):

```
public IEnumerable<string> AllTextsFromTextboxes()
{
    foreach (var control in Page.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        yield return control.Text;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something on these lines, if all the textbox are on the page directly

```
foreach(Control c in Page.Controls)
{
    if (c is TextBox)
    {
        //get the text
    }
}
```

This will not work for child controls for that you will have to recursively iterate

Comment: I'd change it so you use TextBox tb = c as TextBox, then check to see if tb != null to make sure it was a TextBox. Otherwise you have to unbox the control twice.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can put your controls in panel and then iterate and get value. e.g.

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.GetType().Name == "TextBox")
        {
            if (((TextBox)ctrl).Text != string.Empty)
            {
                // do stuff here
            }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void FindSelecedControl(Control control) 
{
    if (control is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)control;
        txt.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < control.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            FindSelecedControl(control.Controls[i]);
        }
    } 
}

foreach (Control control1 in this.Form.Controls) 
{
     FindSelecedControl(control1); 
}
```